# aiogram.utils.exceptions.WrongFileIdentifier: Wrong file identifier/http url specified

Tags: telegram-bot

I want to make a bot to which you send a link to the file, and it sends you the file, but I get an error from the header. I also tried to send InputFile object, but nothing was sent. Here's my code

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.types.input_file import InputFile
 
bot = Bot(token = '')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
 
@dp.message_handler()
async def send_playlist(message: types.Message):
    print(message.text)
    await bot.send_document(message.chat.id, message.text)
 
executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Here's full error text

````
future: <Task finished name='Task-14' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at B:\portable_soft\python\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:331> exception=WrongFileIdentifier('Wrong file identifier/http url specified')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B:\portable_soft\python\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 339, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "B:\portable_soft\python\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 194, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "B:\portable_soft\python\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "B:\portable_soft\python\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 214, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "B:\portable_soft\python\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "B:\portable_soft\adb\file_bot.py", line 12, in send_playlist
    await bot.send_document(message.chat.id, message.text)
  File "B:\portable_soft\python\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 402, in send_document
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_DOCUMENT, payload, files)
  File "B:\portable_soft\python\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 201, in request
    return await api.make_request(self.session, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "B:\portable_soft\python\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 104, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "B:\portable_soft\python\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 78, in check_result
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "B:\portable_soft\python\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 136, in detect
    raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.WrongFileIdentifier: Wrong file identifier/http url specified```
````

Comment: Add the error message in the question.

Comment: @dev-aentgs done

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I don't really understand what you are trying to do.  If you describe your use case a little better, I can probably suggest something more useful.  What are you trying to do with playlists?

```
Here is one way to work with files:

@dp.message_handler(regexp='(^cat[s]?$|puss)')
async def cats(message: types.Message):
    with open('data/cats.jpg', 'rb') as photo:
        '''
        # Old fashioned way:
        await bot.send_photo(
            message.chat.id,
            photo,
            caption='Cats are here ',
            reply_to_message_id=message.message_id,
        )
        '''

        await message.reply_photo(photo, caption='Cats are here ')
```

I actually prefer using FileIDs but I am not sure if that will help you.

Comment: This function is called "send_playlist" because I took it from another project. I don't have a file I need to send, I have a link to it

Comment: try passing the parameters explicitly, like this:

bot.sendDocument(chatid='xxxxx', document='http://yyy.com/zzzz", ... ) and so on

https://dev-docs.aiogram.dev/api/methods/send_document/

Answer (score 0):

Um, just write:

```
await bot.send_message(...)
```

but not:

```
await bot.send_DOCUMENT(...)
```

and if an error pops up:

```
from aiogram import md

await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, md.quote_html(msg.text))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.